# xslt matching all nodes prior to a specific node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to match all the nodes before a specific node. Input XML

```
<story>
  <content>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       ...
    </ul>
    ....
    ....
  </content>
</story>
```

With That as my input XML, I am trying and failing to grab all the `<p>` tags prior to the `<ul>` tags and render them. There could be 0 `<p>` tags or infinite. Any thoughts on how to do this with XSLT 1.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/story/content/p[not(preceding-sibling::ul)]
```

Comment: Wrikken, Are you aware of the fact that this answer is generally incorrect?

Comment: Fixed it by replacing `//` with `/story/content/`.

Comment: Wrikken, No, the answer is still incorrect -- just try it with the sample XML document from my answer -- or one can construct an infinite nummber of XML documents, on which your XPath expression doesn't select the correct node-set.

Comment: OK, re-challenge: provide me the XML in which _my current answer_ fails. To quote you: _"do you have a specific XML document to prove it? This is a good way to make your point -- not just saying that (you think) it is incorrect. "_

Comment: From the very start I provided such XML document -- have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, have you tested `/story/content/p[not(preceding-sibling::ul)]` on it? Because I think you haven't... Don't be afraid to learn something new.

Comment: @Wriken, This expression also depends on a specific XML document and doesn't produce the correct result for other documents.

Comment: Your solution is also not valid for all random paths to that story/content, I refer you to my previous answer to that: http://codepad.org/J9flIiXX

Comment: Wrikken, You have failed to give any counter-example, so far -- and you cannot -- because the expression in my answer is correct. Here is just one document for you: The XPath expression should not select any node, or it is wrong: `<story>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Must not be selected</p></li>
  </ul>
  <content>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <div>
      <p>Must be selected</p>
    </div>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <p>This is the text I want</p>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li><p>This must not be selected</p></li>
    </ul>
    ....
    ....
  </content>
</story>`

Comment: Wrikken, for your convenience I put the counter-example in my answer -- so it is indented and easy to understand.

Comment: Aha, I see where our interpretations differ. I assume the OP wants only `<p>`'s in `/story/content`, you assume he wants any `<p>`, regardless of hierarchy before that. For most practical applications, I assume my interpretation is right (the OP did so after all), as you heavily modified the example and there likely is a reason for the boundary between nodes interpretable as HTML and nodes which aren't, though there is of course a chance that was actually what the OP meant. There usually is less need for non-hierarchical retrieving of nodes, as the hierarchy is one of the core concepts of XML.

Comment: Wrikken, So, you now see that the expression in my answer always, for *any* XML document selects the `p` elements that are before any `ul` elements -- while the expression in your answer doesn't. That's a good achievement.

Comment: I see how your interpretation of the problem differs from mine, yes. Your answer & my answer are solving two distinct, different problems. I maintain that in my _opinion_, my interpretation of the problem at hand was more correct, although yours is more literal, be it less common.

Comment: Wrikken, "less common" ? The correct XPath expression selects exactly the wanted elements in *any* XML document -- unlike yours. And this is the greatest possible generality. And you call this "less common" ???

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//p[not(preceding::ul or ancestor::ul)]
```

**This is generally wrong**:

```
//p[not(preceding-sibling::ul)]
```

because it doesnt select `p` elements that come before any `ul`, but aren't siblings to any `ul`.

**For example, given this XML document**:

```
<story>
  <div>
    <p>Must be selected</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Must not be selected</p></li>
  </ul>
  <content>
    <p>Must not be selected</p>
    <div>
      <p>Must not be selected</p>
    </div>
    <p>Must not be selected</p>
    <p>Must not be selected</p>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li><p>This must not be selected</p></li>
    </ul>
    ....
    ....
  </content>
</story>
```

**the above wrong expression selects**:

```
<p>Must not be selected</p>
<p>Must not be selected</p>
<p>Must not be selected</p>
```

and doesn't select the wanted element:

```
<p>Must be selected</p>
```

**But the correct expression at the start of this answer selects just the wanted `p` element:**

```
<p>Must be selected</p>
```

Comment: You have a point indeed, `+1`. However, ideally, IMHO this would be solved with a `/spefic/path/to/p`'s,so here `/story/content/p[not(preceding-sibling::ul)]` would work (and would be more efficient). When using `//p` as in `p`'s anywhere (either because of lazyness or unknown/dynamic path to them), your answer works better, as long as the `/story/content` is not in an `<ul>` itself, which would mean it finds nothing. So, the answer is not as simple as mine indeed, but yours isn't correct in all situations either a.t.m. :)

Comment: @Wrikken, I am using `//`, only because of the "..." in the provided XML document and the requirement that "all" `p`s with the specified property are selected. As for my answer being "incorrect" -- do you have a specific XML document to prove it? This is a good way to make your point -- not just saying that (you think) it is incorrect.

Comment: I say, that when we start inventing extra nodes, your solution isn't fullproof either, a PHP example: http://codepad.org/qccybreV Did not post that before as I thought _"as long as the /story/content is not in an <ul> itself"_ was clear enough.

Comment: I see I inadvertendly altered your solution somewhat, here's with your literal solution, the point still stands: http://codepad.org/J9flIiXX

Comment: @Wrikken, the XML at that link doesn't contain a single `p` that doesn't have a `ul` before it -- the expression from this answer correctly doesn't select any node in this case. So, you haven't found any counter-example. I do challenge you to find one -- because I know there isn't such! :)

Comment: Dear Dimitri, YOU started to add a `<p>` that did not exist in the example document, if we're allowed to alter the example XML, I added the node around `<story>` instead of in it. My point is _exactly_ that there is no node `//p[not(preceding::ul or ancestor::ul)]` at that point. So, my original solution works for the case given, your solution works better for a dreamed up other case, and I tried to come up with a way to reconcile them into another dreamed up case (which is dropping the `//` for an actual path). All in all, _not_ using `//` does make it more robust, yes or no? And faster too.

Comment: @Wrikken, Re: "My point is exactly that there is no node //p[not(preceding::ul or ancestor::ul)] at that point. " Yes, and that is exactly what the OP wants -- select only those `p` that are before any `ul`. And of course, your solution fails in this case, because it selects `p`s that are after the first `ul`.

Comment: Fine, you win. I say drop the  `//` for a proper path and everything is fine & robust (which in my opinion is still better then your `ancestor`, you say you're exalted. I can live with that if it makes you happy, I bow my head to your awesome knowledge.

Comment: @Wrikken, Irony doesn't help you really learn something new. And of course it doesn't change the facts about which answer is the correct one.

Comment: Guess I appreciate the input, I really do. I used Wrikken's answer and it worked fine. Thanks again both of you